# В каких случаях важно использовать @MockBean, а не @Mock?

Tags: java, юнит-тесты, mocking

В каких случаях важно использовать @MockBean, а не @Mock?

Я нашел следующую информацию по этому вопросу

- @Mock это аналог mock()
- @MockBean это своеобразная обертка над @Mock, которая добавляет мок в контекст
- @MockBean используется в контроллерах. У этих контроллеров указывается аннотация @WebMvcTest.

Но все таки, когда нужно использовать именно @MockBean, а не @Mock?
Для чего добавлять мок в контекст? Для скорости работы за счет переиспользования?
Что изменится если в контроллере использовать @Mock, а не @MockBean?
@MockBean можно использовать только в контроллере? Почему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- @MockBean используйте, когда нужно в контекст spring положить нужный вам замоканный бин(более удобно, чем руками бин подсовывать)
- @Mock используйте в unit тестах где нужно просто замокать класс без дополнительных манимуляций с контекстом spring